# if the user logs in and closes the window and logs in with different account id is the session same for both the users

Tags: java, session

Let us consider a scenario where a user logs into a site and closes the window. Now he logs in into the site with a different user id. Will the second user have the same session id and the first user id?

Comment: Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user. You have to invalidate the user session after some time interval. Check what is `HttpSession` in JavaEE Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A session ID is a unique number that a Web site's server assigns a
>   specific user for the duration of that user's visit (session). The
>   session ID can be stored as a cookie, form field, or URL (Uniform
>   Resource Locator). Some Web servers generate session IDs by simply
>   incrementing static numbers. However, most servers use algorithms that
>   involve more complex methods, such as factoring in the date and time
>   of the visit along with other variables defined by the server
>   administrator.
>
> Every time an Internet user visits a specific Web site, a new session
>   ID is assigned. Closing a browser and then reopening and visiting the
>   site again generates a new session ID. However, the same session ID is
>   sometimes maintained as long as the browser is open, even if the user
>   leaves the site in question and returns. In some cases, Web servers
>   terminate a session and assign a new session ID after a few minutes of
>   inactivity.

From [HERE](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/session-ID)

Comment: If the user closes the browser, then the server does not come to know. So the session does not get invalidated. Hence if the user again logs in with a different account id, the server will still maintain the same session id unless we handle in code.

Answer (score 0):

**Never**, Session id is always unique for every request if you want to remember the user across all requests then you have to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

Use session.inValidate() method in the logout code. So when the user logs out, that current session is destroyed. A new session is created for the next userid.